# drop down menu php with condition

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a code which has a form that inputs surface area. db_connect.php connects the database. I am trying to populate a drop down list with a condition that all values that have surface area greater than the value typed into the text field will be displayed in the text field. But when I try to run the code, i'm getting all the values. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hi</title>
    </head>
        <body>

        <form>
            <p> surface area : <input name = "sa" type = "text"> </p>
        <br>
        </form>


        <select name="areas">
                <?php 
                $sa = $_POST['sa'];
               include "db_connect.php";
               $displayArea = "SELECT area FROM details where area > '".$sa."'" ;
               $sql = mysqli_query($link, $displayArea);
               echo "<option> Select </option>";
               while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
               {  
                echo "<option value=\"areas\">" . $row['area'] . "</option>";
               }
               ?>
        </select>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You will need to use ajax to populate the `select` list when the `sa` input has been filled in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: This PHP code runs *immediately* when the HTML is being rendered by the server. `$_POST['sa']` *does not exist* until something posts to this page. As GluePear says, use AJAX to solve this, make a secondary request after rendering the initial page, and each time `sa` is changed, make a new request.

Answer (score 0):

first you need a submit button into the form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then if you are using POST you have to specify it as a Form method:

```
<form method="post">
```

Then add:

```
$sa = $_POST['sa'];
echo("[".$sa."]");
```

to see if "sa" is populated.

If you add a value and click on "Submit" you will see the result.